# Access object attributes when the object is in an array C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm using C# on Visual Studio, as part of a Windows Form, but nothing to do with the form is referenced here.

So, I have an class called node:

```
class node
{
    public int value;
    public int NodeLeft;
    public int NodeRight;

    public node(int value, int NodeLeft, int NodeRight)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.NodeLeft = NodeLeft;
        this.NodeRight = NodeRight;
    }

    public int getValue() { return value; }
    public int getNodeLeft() { return NodeLeft; }
    public int getNodeRight() { return NodeRight; }


}
```

In the rest of my program, an array holds a series of these nodes, each with a value, `NodeLeft` and `NodeRight`. However, until a certain point is reached, `NodeLeft` and `NodeRight` can't be assigned because there is nothing to assign them to. So, after a condition is met, a while loop is meant to run where each loop causes the original set of node objects to be reassigned to have a `NodeLeft` and `NodeRight` value - however, what I've currently got isn't working.

I'm expecting it to assign value, `NodeLeft` and `NodeRight` to the relevant values found in the array. However, it gives me the following error:

> cannot convert from "method group" to "int"

I'm currently using this:

```
newtree[arrayincreasecounter] = new node(newtree[arrayincreasecounter].getValue, newtree[arrayincreasecounter + arrayincreasecounterup].getValue, newtree[arrayincreasecounter + arrayincreasecounterup + 1].getValue);
```

What I'm (poorly) attempting to do is get the value of each node object in the array and assign it to the `NodeLeft` and `NodeRight`.

`arrayincreasecounter` is just a loop variable starting at 0.
`arrayincreasecounterup` is a variable I'm using to make a specific sequence.
`newtree` is the overall object that has the attribute of the array of node objects.

Note: This is a crude attempt at making my own binary tree class, and no, I can't just use the built in one.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a question. Please describe the current and expected behavior, ideally with a Minmal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: In a common implementation of a (binary) Tree each `node` would hold references to other nodes and there's usually no array holding all of the nodes

Comment: A suggestion: Use PascalCase for object and property names. Use camelCase for variable and argument names. `arrayincreasecounter` just looks like a random assortment of letters to me unless I concentrate. And you don't want me to have to concentrate in a code review :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValue` is a method.  To call the method, use empty `()` aka function call operator

```
newtree[arrayincreasecounter] = new node(
    newtree[arrayincreasecounter].getValue(), 
    newtree[arrayincreasecounter + arrayincreasecounterup].getValue(), 
    newtree[arrayincreasecounter + arrayincreasecounterup + 1].getValue());
```

Or you can use properties with only a getter to achieve similar results

```
class node
{
    public int value { get; }
    public int NodeLeft { get; }
    public int NodeRight { get; }

    public node(int value, int NodeLeft, int NodeRight)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.NodeLeft = NodeLeft;
        this.NodeRight = NodeRight;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
newtree[arrayincreasecounter] = new node(
    newtree[arrayincreasecounter].value, 
    newtree[arrayincreasecounter + arrayincreasecounterup].value, 
    newtree[arrayincreasecounter + arrayincreasecounterup + 1].value);
```

Comment: @DomBeasley ;) it happens

Comment: I'd recommend renaming `value` to `Value` in the sample code, to follow .NET naming conventions - as well as renaming the class and the `NodeLeft` and `NodeRight` parameters too.